# DataColumn: combine columns and values into a string

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation, datacolumn

I'd like to use LINQ to take a datarow, and parse out the datacolumn names with their values.

So if I had a dataRow with the following columns and values:

```
DataColumn column1 with value '1'
DataColumn column2 with value 'ABC'
```

I'd like to have a string returned as "column1 = '1' and column2 = 'ABC'"

**** code should not care about the column names, nor the number of columns in the table.****

Purpose being, to filter a dataTable like:

```
var newRows = myTable.Select ("column1 = '1' and column2 = 'ABC'");
```

I can parse out the columns of the table like this:

```
string[] columnName = myTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(cn => cn.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

But I need to also extract values from a target row.
It feels like this might be a start:

```
{
  string[] columnNames = existingTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(cn => cn.ColumnName).ToArray();
  foreach (DataRow oldRow in existingTable.Rows)
  {
    var criteria = string.Join("and", columnNames, oldRow.ItemArray);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the column names and rows without actually referencing them. Is this what you're trying to do:

```
var table = new DataTable();

var column = new DataColumn {ColumnName = "column1"};
table.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn {ColumnName = "column2"};
table.Columns.Add(column);

var row = table.NewRow();
row["column1"] = "1";
row["column2"] = "ABC";
table.Rows.Add(row);

string output = "";
foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows)
{
    output = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                  .Aggregate(output, (current, c) => current + 
                      string.Format("{0}='{1}' ", c.ColumnName, (string) r[c]));
    output = output + Environment.NewLine;
}

// output should now contain "column1='1' column2='ABC'"
```

You can create extension methods out of this too, which operate both on a `DataTable` (for all rows) or a `DataRow` (for a single row):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToText(this DataRow dr)
    {
        string output = "";
        output = dr.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                   .Aggregate(output, (current, c) => current +
                       string.Format("{0}='{1}'", c.ColumnName, (string)dr[c]));

        return output;
    }

    public static string ToText(this DataTable table)
    {
        return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                    .Aggregate("", (current, dr) => current + dr.ToText() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this gets you in the right direction

*EDIT* Added solution using reflection since that is more in line with what you are wanting to accomplish

```
void Main()
{
    List<MyClass> myColl = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass() { myFirstProp = "1", mySecondProp = "ABC" } };

    foreach (MyClass r in myColl)
    {
        List<string> rPropsAsStrings = new List<string>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in r.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            rPropsAsStrings.Add(String.Format("{0} = {1}", propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(r, null)));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" and ", rPropsAsStrings.ToArray()));
    }


}

public class MyClass
{
    public string myFirstProp { get; set; }
    public string mySecondProp { get; set; }
}
```

The below uses `Linq` with strong typed properties

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new DataTable("ParentTable");
DataColumn column;
DataRow row;

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = typeof(string);
column.ColumnName = "column1";
table.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = typeof(string);
column.ColumnName = "column2";
table.Columns.Add(column);

row = table.NewRow();
row["column1"] = "1";
row["column2"] = "ABC";
table.Rows.Add(row);

var results = from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
                select String.Format("column1 = {0}, column2 = {1}", myRow[0], myRow[1]);

foreach (string r in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

Comment: thx for your reply... the code example i provided didn't require knowledge of the actual column names, and although I didn't mention it as a requirement, a LINQ solution I think could make that happen.

Comment: You would likely not be using Datatables with linq either, was more a example based on your example. I assume you are using linq over a collection of an object, in which case you can certainly exclude the strongly typed names by looping the properties of your type with reflection but at that point its not linq doing the cacatenation but The Reflection loop itself.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case yes, I am using LINQ against a DataTable. I've been using LINQ against DT's for quite some time, as subjectively required of course...  Thank you again for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend mapping to a class, and then adding another property which combines both of them!

Comment: Normally I would but I am extending an application which doesn't lend itself well to to these types of these types of extends.